# Chrome autofill issue

Tags: html

I have facing an issue related to browser autofill. In my html code I have user `autocomplete="off"` for preventing auto fill. I have tried with `autocomplete="nope"` also. While using `"nope"` method its working in Chrome browser but not in Mozilla. Could you please give proper solution for preventing autofill in both Chrome and Mozilla.[image: Showing autofill...]

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'new-value' as below.

autocomplete = "new-value"

Comment: I have tried this this. But not working in Mozilla (my version is 62.0.3) :(

Comment: I suggest you to handle this in two different ways for these two scenarios. I am not sure what framework you are using. Please refer below psudo code. if(chrome){ // handle chrome scenario }else if(mozilla){//handle mozilla scenario}